# WebStorm and PHP syntax highlighting in WebStorm

Tags: syntax-highlighting, webstorm, textmatebundles

I have WebStorm and really like it. I don't use PHP very often, but I'm working on a project that uses it...

So, I'm trying to get basic syntax highlighting in WebStorm.

I've tried using this plugin already (incompatible):

http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6610

And I've followed the steps in these threads:

[Webstorm: how to extend to handle PHP files or even just higlight code correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11683978/webstorm-how-to-extend-to-handle-php-files-or-even-just-higlight-code-correctly)

[Is it possible to get Ruby syntax highlighting in PHPStorm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16451359/is-it-possible-to-get-ruby-syntax-highlighting-in-phpstorm/16451778#16451778)

I am using this textmate bundle:

https://github.com/textmate/php.tmbundle

It's being recognized by WebStorm, and the proper files are being associated with TextMate bundles, yet I still have no syntax highlighting.

At this point, I've just written all the stuff without the highlighting, but it seems a bit ridicules that I cannot get it to work.

I sent an email to technical support, and they just pointed me back to those resources and then suggested that I buy PHPStorm. And the IDE keeps suggesting that I buy IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate.

Has anybody else run into this problem?

Comment: did you ever get php highlighting working in Webstorm?

Comment: @Damon no. As far as I know, it can't be done. I haven't tried in a while though, perhaps there's a fix for it now. I just use phpstorm when I'm working on a project with php... :/

Comment: I was able to get some somewhat limited PHP syntax highlighting on webstorm using this settings import: https://github.com/a2net/WebStorm-php-Syntax-Highlight-with-WordPress-functions

Comment: @Damon Using this plugin with WebStorm 2017/2018 purely breaks it, php files don't even open. Don't recommend using it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

https://github.com/textmate/php.tmbundle bundle uses non-documented 'injection' - feature that's not currently supported - thus no highlighting is actually recognized. See [RUBY-14273](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-14273)

Comment: A way to add PHP syntax highlighting to Webstorm would make the answer POP. is there any way?